# How do you keep a django digital ocean droplet live at all times?

Tags: django

If I purchase a droplet from digital ocean and install Django on it and get a basic hello world webpage going, how could I run this server and keep it live without a terminal staying open 24/7?

For example, if the droplet I.P. Address was 162.243.250.17:8001, and I entered this code:

```
python manage.py runserver 162.243.250.17:8001
```

I'll get the output:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
January 31, 2014 - 22:58:23
Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'django_test.settings'
Starting development server at http://162.243.250.17:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But so how do I keep this going even if I close my terminal? I'm going to need a website to stay live.

**UPDATE I found the solution**

This is the first step if your production server/droplet is running Linux

in order for your website to go live as if it were production ready, you need to install nginx like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

finally, get your home page to go live with a "Welcome to nginx!" like home page by entering this in your terminal:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

That's it!

The next step would be to make it so that the Django development server's address to replace the "Welcome to nginx!" page. I'm going to start working on that now, I'll keep this thread updated with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the way to run django based webserver. You need to use apache/nginx.
If you use nginx you can combine it with wsgi container like gunicorn and supervisord.

For example, look here http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ or search for these terms.

Comment: This is a great tutorial, thank you for sharing this

Answer (score 1):

What eran said is absolutely right: you would never use the built in django server for anything in production, and use nginx or gunicorn/uwsgi.

However, you seem to be learning Django at this point. So, even if you just close the terminal (if you are SSH-ing) or close the browser, the program should run as long as you do not press ctrl + c, or kill the running server. However, you will find out that it crashes a lot and is very slow.

Learning nginx and uwsgi is too much work at this point. Learn django properly on your laptop first, and when you feel comfortable enough, then maybe deploy on digital ocean. Why spend money, albeit it is pretty cheap at $5.

Comment: No, if the server is running inside an SSH session it will exit when the session terminates.

Comment: I did not know that actually. Thanks.